# Pulling data from Controller to Shared View / Layout

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using ASP.NET MVC4 to create a website in which content is loaded using PartialViews and jQuery. My main page looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li id="recent">Recent</li>
    <li id="home">Home</li>
    <li id="books">Books</li>
</ul>

<div id="content"></div>
```

And the jQuery looks like:

```
$("#recent").on("click", function () {
    $("#content").load("/Recent/Load");
});

$("#home").on("click", function () {
    $("#content").load("/Home/Load");
});

$("#Books").on("click", function () {
    $("#books").load("/Books/Load");
});
```

[Here's a jsFiddle, not working because no MVC obviously.](http://jsfiddle.net/3PZTx/)

The `<li>`s act as links, loading PartialViews from their respective Controllers into `<div id="content">`.

I want the "Recent" `<li>` to be colored red when new Books have been added in the last 24 hours. The logic for determining if new Books have been added exists in the Controller.

One solution I have is to have the "Recent" `<li>` as a separate PartialView and perform the following:

**RecentBooks.cshtml:**

```
<li id="recent" style="background-color: red;">Recent</li>
```

**NoRecentBooks.cshtml:**

```
<li id="recent">Recent</li>
```

And then, on every link click, use jQuery to call the Controller that returns one of these two PartialViews.

This seems a very cumbersome way of updating one attribute on one line of code. It will work, yes, but is there another method I am ignorant of? One this doesn't involve PartialViews?

Comment: partial view is the only option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles upon this, the answer is that there is no way to do this other than with PartialViews.

Comment: That is simply not true, this would be easily done with something like KnockoutJS, You would simply return the data in JSON format from the controller (or web api) and then do what you need to do on the client with Javascript.

Comment: then make it answered my friend

Answer (score 0):

Yes its a good way to change partial view.Another way is use AJAX to load Partial view,

```
function functionName(controller, method, data, onSuccess, onError) {
    return $.post(baseUrl + '/' + controller + '/' + method, data, onSuccess).error(function (err) {
         if (onError) onError(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm already using jQuery to load the PartialView. I'm asking whether or not there is a way to do this without PartialViews.

Comment: In another way you need to change whole view or you need to change your current view content via replacing HTML